# Method to Interpret User input in TextBox Live - Similar to WMD preview here on SO

Tags: user-input, interpreter, live

I am looking to find a way to interpret user input as they type it (and eventually perform some types of actions as it happens based on their input)  This is intended for a web based application.

So far I have a way that I can update a Label whenever the user hits enter, but I would like it so that the text updates on any keypress.  Currently the code in a C# website in Visual Studio looks like this:

```
  protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = TextBox1.Text;
}
```

What would be the best language or approach to making it so any time a key is pressed within the box?

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to use Javascript (specifically the [`onkeyup`](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/Event-onMethod/onKeyUpExample.htm) function).